# What is Mongodb Atlas Functions ip range?

Tags: mongodb-atlas

I need to make a call to a MySQL database whose access is restricted by IP from the MongoDB Atlas Function.

For this to work, I need to allow the MongoDB Atlas Function IP ranges on the MySQL server.

I can't find anything about this in the documentation. Do you know the IP ranges to authorize?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find MongoDB Atlas Function IP with this snippet of code:

```
const https = require('https');

https.get('https://api.ipify.org?format=json', (res) => {
    console.log('statusCode:', res.statusCode);
    console.log('headers:', res.headers);

    let data = '';
    res.on('data', (chunk) => {
        data += chunk;
    });
    res.on('end', () => {
        console.log(data);
    });
}).on('error', (e) => {
    console.error(e);
});
```

Once the function is deployed, the IP doesn't often change even when you update the function's code.